# Are there thought experiments about physicalism?

Tags: reference-request, consciousness, identity, physicalism

Other than **Mary's Room** and maybe Searle's **Chinese Room** are there any other interesting thought experiments ***against*** the ideas of physicalism, and the idea our minds are identical to our brains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was surprised to learn that [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/if-zombies-are-possible-would-that-imply-that-physicalism-is-false?rq=1) (from the "Related" sidebar), regarding [philosophical zombies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_zombie), is actually used in published philosophical works as a refutation of physicalism (David Chalmers is a name mentioned there).

My dismissal of it would be that claiming, "Zombies are physically identical to us but lack consciousness, therefore physicalism is false," is an extremely blatant form of [circular reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) -- the assertion that consciousness is not physical is implicit in the assertion that zombies are physically identical to conscious human beings but do not possess consciousness.  The claim might as well read, "Consciousness is not physical, therefore physicalism is false".  No thought experiment required!

I think p-zombies are a great concept for other reasons ;)  But if they exist, their defining characteristic would be that they are indistinguishable from normal people but lack consciousness.  That we would consider them indistinguishable from us does not equate to them being physically identical, even if we could not identify the difference with our fine tooth combs.

Comment: A philosophical zombie is like a thought experiment 'made' by Raymond Smullyan. About a special 'potion' that if one drinks it it destoys the person's soul without altering the person's physical functions or 'systems'. If the person drinks it they 'look' and 'act' like they always have (an indirect appeal to the idea we are just 'biochemical robots' performing 'automated' tasks). Though unlike the p-zombie thet don't rot , they look human. Smullyan's thought experiment is what if a fellow who has the potion drinks it at night when he's half asleep and he wakes up thinking he hasn't drunk it..

Comment: The argument is not prima facie circular. It says that zombies are conveivable (nothing in a physical description however complex has phenomenal properties) therefore possible, and concludes that physicalism is false. The contentious (possibly question begging) part is going from conceivability to possibility.

Comment: I don't think the claim that the argument is begging the question is refuted by saying that the thing is "conceivable". Like classic circular argument: You are  a liar. You say that you are not lying? Well that proves my point, because I know that you are a liar, so when you say you are not, that is a lie, I have just caught you in a lie. QED. To rebut that it is not a circular argument because it is conceivable that the person is a liar ... of course it is. But the fact that it is "conceivable" does not prove it is true.

Comment: @quen_tin Gotta agree with Jay here -- making a distinction between "conceivable" and "possible" just shifts where the question gets begged. The physicalist would say, sure, p-zombies based on their primary characteristic (lack of consciousness) might be *possible*, but there will be something physically different about their minds reflecting this. Saying, "Oh, no, that's not the proper definition of p-zombie, it's possible without there being any difference simply because I *conceive* of it" is blatantly circular again.  One could claim absolutely anything with "I conceive it so" as evidence.

Comment: Also, saying zombies are conceivable therefore real allows that a physical interpretation of all reality is conceivable (many have imagined it) and therefore real. So we are in Montaigne territory -- you win either way because everybody loses. Fine with me, as noted below I go with Hegel here, and am a strict 'physicalism agnostic'. If we ever decide this proposition, the purpose of intelligence will have been served, and we will have to move on to something else

Comment: @jay this is different: you cannot deduce anything from the possibility that someone else is lying (because the other possibility remains). But you can deduce something from the sole possibility of p-zombies: that physical aspects are not enough to spexify the whole state of affair.

Comment: @quen_tin By what stretch of the imagination -- other than arbitrary *circular* fiat -- can you say that "you can deduce something from the sole possibility of p-zombies: that physical aspects are not enough to spexify the whole state of affair".  Either p-zombies are 1) Defined as possessing or lacking a *non-physical* trait, in which case the argument is circular because you've defined consciousness as a non-physical trait OR 2) P-zombies are defined by a lack of consciousness (without stating this is by your definition non-physical); if physicalism is true, they are physically different.

Comment: @goldilocks I agree it might shift the problem, but for the matter of precision: the defining characteristic of p-zombie is to be physically indistinct from real persons but phenomenally distinct. Physicalists must deny that they are possible.

Comment: @goldilocks Sure it seems absurd to get factual conclusions from conceivability alone. The point is that our current conception of the physical allows p-zombie as a logical possibility. Under my interpretation, the conclusion is not factual: it is that physicalism is inconsistent I would say (either our conception of the physical is false, or not everything is physical).

Comment: @quen_tin Yes, that's why it's circular, and as I said, you *could make absolutely any kind of (rationally coherent) claim this way*.  I could define p-zombies as evidence of the presence of invaders from planet Zibnaycon-27, simply by saying they contain an element unknown on earth and tacking it onto the end of the periodic table.  So: since such beings are conceivable, we now have proof that beings from Zibnaycon-27 might be living amongst us.  This is a really, really poor argument and I am surprised it got passed around at all.

Comment: Re: "our current conception of the physical allows p-zombie as a logical possibility" -> No, *your* current conception of the physical does.  A physicalist's *does not*.  If they exist, they are physically different in some minor but significant way.

Comment: Sorry but if it's conceivable, it's a logical possibility (by definition of conceivable). Again the zombie-argument is a conceptual argument, not a factual one and your example is thus irrelevant (you draw no conclusion on how we conceive of zibnaycon for example). The discussion could go on for long, I'll move it to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18164/discussion-between-quen-tin-and-goldilocks).

Comment: Could an Automaton with an A.I. system that 'accurately' approximates a Human emotional and cognitive 'mind-brain'( on that passes the Turing Test) be considered a technological equivalent of a P-zombie? A Techno-zombie?

Comment: @user128932 Not if the claim is that a p-zombie is physically identical to a human being (which I'm saying would make the argument circular).

Comment: What if the Automaton with an A.I. system that approximates a human mind-brain is a technological approximation of what is considered a p-zombie?

Comment: Since it's still not physically identical to a human being, it wouldn't be an argument either for or against physicalism.  But if you could produce two such robots that were physically identical to each other and prove that only one of them possessed consciousness, then that would be analogous to the p-zombie argument against physicalism, because it implies that possession of consciousness is a non-physical trait.

Comment: What is a non-physical trait? Is that an emergent trait? If an A.I. system has a set of programs it has to use constantly for proper function ; if these programs have invariant processes or traits that it 'must' maintain for any self-sustaining ability would these invariant processes be considered important non-physical traits?

Comment: I don't see why any aspect of an A.I. system would be considered non-physical.  To the extent that it must maintain state of whatever sort, that's physical, just like a regular computer.  Your web browser executable is stored on a physical medium; when invoked that data is loaded into another physical medium (RAM) and various physical process allow it to interact with the OS and hardware.  To the extent that the A.I. involves emergent properties (however defined), those would be physical too.  What else could they be?

Comment: If a human mind was entirely a physical system I don't see how neuro- plactity could 'work' in a neuro-mechanical system as the 'mind' is imagined. I mean a typical computer system or an A.I. that is supposed to be entirely physical and mechanical can not restructure itself to 'make' 'new' programs or new important structures as it would have to do if it had a type of plasticity. So by analogy a human mind , if it is a physical mechanical couldn't have plasticity.

Comment: @201044 [Neuroplasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroplasticity), the brain's ability to restructure itself physically, is no longer questioned by mainstream science.  It's simply part of the accepted paradigm about how it works.   This is why, e.g., people can have BCI implants that allow them to learn to operate a mouse cursor, etc. with their "mind".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Nagle

Comment: Neuroplasticity exists in the mind and if we are 'neuro-mechanical' systems similar to the electro-chemical mechanical systems of an A.I. system then by analogy an A.I system could have a type of 'neuroplasticity' for machines or what you might call 'program plasticity'. The ability to rewrite 'internal algorithms or even make 'new' ones.( Ones that are not just a recombination of ideas of the systems programmers.)

Comment: If an A.I. system is entirely physical or 'mechanical' and it is meant to mimic the human mind-brain YET a physical mechanical computing system can not reprogram itself or significantly alter itself ; yet again this is supposed to closely mimic the brain which can reprogram itself or alter itself with 'plasticity', this is a contradiction.

Comment: This is a good argument against the mind being 'purely mechanical' or totally reproducible by a system of interacting programs.

Comment: You are using implied & reductive definitions of *mechanism* for their rhetorical value in some political arena:  "Oh look how my opponent wants to convince us we are all just machines!"  If we had any audience besides ourselves, or I was running for public office, this might be of value, but since neither thing is true, all I can say is wishy-washy defensive thinking and rhetorical pluck is not any style of "good argument".  I do not believe in God and there is no meaning for me in contemplating anything beyond the physical.   *So I do not understand what you could be contrasting that to.*

Comment: Maybe some biologists and other scientists who think the human mind is only a 'machine' ; this may limit their ability to analyze the 'mind's'  capabilities if it not just reducible to mechanical subsystems. This is not a political idea , I'm just implying the mind might have functions that are not analogous to 'neural computers'.

Comment: @201044 I certainly don't believe the current state of 'neural whatever' science (or AI research, etc) is up to completely (or anywhere near 'completely') explaining the physical functioning of the brain, but that does not mean that the mind has components beyond that.  This sort of goes along with the fact that our scientific knowledge generally is not perfect.  If your evaluation of physicalism (the philosophy) is based on the current state of neuroscience, then of course it is lacking.  But the idea is not that we already understand it, but about the means by which it might be understood.

Comment: ...Or not understood (various much more pie-in-the-sky assertions about some non-physical, completely speculative, essentially anything-is-true and everything-is-permitted aspect of the 'mind').   I do see physicalism as about **closing doors that need to be closed**, shut, forgotten -- things from our superstitious past, and the metaphysical baggage they have spawned even once superstition is ostensibly rejected.

Comment: Interesting observatons ; my original question was if there are thought experiments  that point out the importance of the functions of the mind and that they are not just 'mechanical-like' interactions of neurons and their signalling. I did not think it was philosophically 'illegal' to raise such questions as some have suggested. Functionalism is a recognised philosophical idea and not associated to superstition.

Comment: If you mean functionalism a la Compte & Spencer, I do not see how that necessarily involves metaphysics, i.e., it and physicalism are completely compatible.  I'm not sure if you're trying to invoke a reductionist view of the physical by claiming it is about explaining the mind in terms of " 'mechanical-like' interactions of neurons and their signalling"  -- this is why the term *physicalism* superseded *materialism*. It's also why things like Searle's room miss the point.   You can use Searle's room as the basis for solipsism if you like.  There are politics behind all those things, I think.

Comment: So "illegal", no, but just very suspicious.  In a culture that was completely free from theological and metaphysical baggage -- a culture that had never considered the world to be anything but physical -- it would just seem absurd to suggest that the mind, or the experience of consciousness, is something other than physical.   Keeping in mind WRT descriptions of "neurons" or whatever that while [the map is *obviously not* the territory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation), there is no reason to believe either is something other than physical.

Comment: Isn't the thought experiment of a billion individuals in China all interacting as if they were the neurons of a 'giant' brain or mass mind ; isn' this against the idea of a PURELY physical mind-brain system?

Comment: Not if you assert the individual "neurons" have some (mysterious, inevitably purely speculative and imagination based) non-physical component, lol.  This is the Occam's razor basis of physicalism: If you assert there is some purely speculative, non-physical reality, then you must accept all such potential realities, since they are all equally unprovable.  And there is an infinite number of them.  And many of them will be mutually incompatible. This is sort of *the opposite of reasoning* and it is a waste of the human mind to indulge in it on too serious a level (IMO).

Comment: Does the thought experiment of a billion chinese people for a day doing all sorts of instructed activity to 'mimic' the actions of neurons and their connections show anything about the mind?

Comment: Sounds more like art than thought experiment.  If it is supposed to prove anything, no doubt there could be someone out there with some supernatural theory who would be happy to accept it as evidence.   E.g., that the Earth is really a giant, omnipotent aardvark rolled into a ball, and people are facets of its consciousness.  Empirical facts are just things the aardvark thinks up to conceal itself and leave us uncertain. Go nuts.  Why not?

Comment: User 128932 makes some very interesting points. I don't know why many of the replies seem so inherently discouraging. Seems like 'trials by intimidation' rather than a useful sharing of ideas....

Comment: An interesting point now seems to be that you would refer to "user 128932" in the third person, as if it were someone other than yourself.  What interesting points is it that you think you have made, regardless of the username?

Comment: @selfidentifiedAsEvil ; I know user 128932 is myself but as your administraters are not allowing me to claim all my additional points because of some problem I had with my gmail I can still comment on my own previous work. Something other users are not allowed to do. And therefore I'm one of the few encouraging. commentators of user128932.

Comment: Fair enough. lol.  I'm still not sure what you are trying to get at, but it is probably better taken up in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27017/about-the-philosophy-of-physicalism Beware I think those disappear if you don't say anything for 2 weeks.

Comment: The thought experiment of a billion Chinese people being told to do various tasks for one day that are all orchestrated to be like one mass mind is a possible example of a thought experiment against the idea every facet of our thinking is all dependent on physical substructures within our brains.

Comment: That's not a thought experiment and seems to have nothing to do with anything.  Physicalism only implies "it is all within our brains" if you want to resort to absurdist reductionism because you have committed a proiri  to the idea that physicalism can only be false. Then over and over again you construct a straw man and say, "Look! This man is made of straw therefore the earth is flat!".

Comment: What is a non-physical thing or process anyway? Some mysterious category of phenomena or processes that anti- dualist thinkers use to label what is not physical. If non-physical quality is impossible for the mind-brain system or such a possibility doesn't exist at all then the non-physical concept is a 'straw man' itself. Anyway maybe the 'mind' is neither physical or non-physical.

Comment: Yes, this is where Occam's razor applies.  If you are going to multiply entities unnecessarily, you might as well just multiply them as much as you like and make up anything that suits your fancy and say, "Well, it could be true that..." since,  in fact, *there is **nothing** that can be proven true or untrue in that paradigm*.  In short, "truth" vs. "falsity" would be meaningless. This is the basis of physicalism.  People who do not like reasoning logically do not like physicalism.

Comment: Are there any thought experiments that are for physicalism?

Answer (score 4):

I think the idea of "arguing against physicalism" (or for that matter arguing for it) is basically misleading in a deep way, and is an attempt to do religion by philosophical means.  Not that that is bad, but it is theology and needs to recognize that association.  If you answered the question of the tenability of physicalism clearly and definitively in either direction, it would remain in some other form, ever-retreating and impossible to really address.

First of all, pro-mind, or even pro-quale arguments are not anti-physical arguments.  One can accept physicalism and not believe the mind and the brain are identical.  Richard Dawkins' notion of memetic ecology is clearly physicalist without dismissing the idea of mind or that minds contain language-borne ideas that have a life of their own and survive the death of the brain.  Jung was alternately completely physicalist and an outright mystic, without contradicting himself.  Tavistock psychoanalyts can accept the brain as physical and still see ideas unconsciously make their way from one person to another in a group, play out manipulations of the group mind and get resolved without ever being noticed, much less articulated, by the minds/brains processing them.  So physical does not even rule out mysterious or spooky.

The mind can be an epiphenomenon of the brain and its network of interrelations with other brains without it ceasing to exist, and without all of philosophy collapsing into neurology.  Just as atomism does not contradict our ability to make rigid structures, physicalism does not contradict our ability to discuss ideas that transcend individuals.

Second, to my mind, this is a clearly undecidable proposition.  Given phenomena, you can either assume something or nothing is behind them.  If we got behind them and discovered a basis, the 'nothing' camp would immediately simply add that basis to the list of things we consider physical, and, the end of time notwithstanding, the 'something' camp would still find unexplained phenomena.

We discovered electricity, something that exists in some weird distributed state that freely reaches across empty space, something as spectral as we could imagine in the 18th century, and when it stopped being entirely mysterious, instead of declaring there to be another layer of reality, we just decided it was physics.  Then we discovered quantum mechanics, something that seems to strictly limit our ability to predict physical behavior, and instead of deciding we needed another name for this deeper level of causation, we devised wave functions and declared "the distribution of the possibility of the location of a particle in wave form", to be physics.

Our ability to declare things physical has no bounds.  So like God and atheism, physicalism and non-physicalism are not a philosophically addressable questions, they are faiths.  People who insist on deciding undecidable propositions have an agenda outside the truth.  So, what is the agenda behind rejecting physicalism?  Why put up with the question?

Third, we have already seen the 'synthetic' moment where this dichotomy ceases to be a useful guide.  We got to Hegel, and the notion of human history as the attempt for the physical and the mental aspects of the universe to find common ground -- for matter (which is also God) to understand itself.  So there is an 'agnostic' position here, we have middle ground, but we never walk over it.  We keep the dichotomy clean, as though all intermediate positions are nonsense.

Finally, this argument tends to exist to eliminate other arguments, and that, to me, is an indicator of its ultimately destructive nature.  If you decide something is or is not physical, you seem to have answered a question about what it actually is, an how it works.  But you have not actually begun to try to do so.  Once it is physical or non-physical, depending upon who you are, you can relegate it to some science or to some religious position, and stop considering it philosophically until that science or that palliative framing gets to some unresolvable question.  But that is just laziness.  There is no reason only quantum mechanics seems philosophical to us, and not field theory, or thermodynamics.  We just don't like the fact that those other sciences have huge historical weight, and a lot of facts in them.

Comment: Just asking for thought experiments that criticize Physicalism is not a religious act.  Do some philosophers treat physicalism like a religious viewpoint?

Comment: The majority here seem to disagree with me, but I see materialism and atheism as religious positions and many of their holders in the past (when they were more of a persecuted minority) have as well.  Even if you do not see them as outright religious, they share the same basic problem that adherents are free to rearrange their statements so that arguments never 'connect'.  One cannot successfullly attack or defend physicalism to adherents of the opposite camp.

Comment: Materialism and atheism are certainly treated like religious positions but regarding my original question , forgetting about physicalism have there been any philosophers that have argued we and what we think of as our 'minds' are not just a physical brain. That what we think of as our 'mental' self controlling system of our present thinking ,our emotional reactions, e.t.c., is not just a complex sequence of interacting stimulated neurons. Also a physical system of interacting stimulated neurons can not reprogram itself , I don't think. Similarly Idon't think a neural net can reprogram itself.

Comment: But all these classical arguments are arguments that the mind exists -- Plato's cave is, Aristotle's prime mover is.  Descartes' 'cogito' is.  All of Spinoza, Liebnitz, Berkeley, Whitehead...  Your question implies more.  It implies that if the mind exists, thinking does not always leave a physical trace.  That would be unprovable.  If the two things always happen together, there is no reason to assume the physical manifestation causes or is caused by the mental one.  It is so common a **completely unproven** assumption that when it gets ignore yet again, one needs to make some noise about it.

Comment: One is free to **prove** the absence of a bias, when it is asserted.  No attempt was made.  Can anyone give me an example of an anti-physicalist who was in no way religiously motivated, or a physicalist who is an acknowledged theist?  Having to state 'I am not a racist' does not increase the odds you are, in fact, not a racist in any way

Comment: You are also free to **actually meet** my objections, and not simply claim them away -- Can you demonstrate that this is not an undecidable proposition, by offering some accepted boundary between what we can and cannot declare physical?  Or can you tell me what use you intent to put to the answer, that no one would consider religious?

Comment: I believe thinking can leave physical traces ; one can think in certain ways to 'train oneself' to 'perform' certain behaviours so these self-reprogrammed behavioural patterns can be repeated or 'nearly' repeated. This would probably 'restucture' various physical features in the brain 'involved' in the active 'behavioural programs'. So one probably can change the physical brain 'subsystems' just by thinking. I don't think changes in the physical structure of the brain can by themselves (with NO 'help' from any behavioural 'programs') cause definite changes in the way one thinks.

Comment: I believe the mind exist and it always leaves physical traces. But the mind is like a self-sustaining 'conglomeration' of hopefully useful and relevent 'behavioural programs' and various other information packages that all interact like a constantly self-orienting 'information and info.-program co-operative'. A self-sustaining 'behavioural program' management system that can always reprogram parts of itself 'if deemed' necessary ( yet not in ways that cause disfunction). So the mind is really 'about' reprogrammable behavioural patterns and how to manage this.

Comment: To your first point, look up Phineas Gage.  The physical brain can be impaired in ways that 'unhinge the soul'.  To the second, that means arguments for the mind are not arguments against physicalism, and the question states more than you mean.  Finally, neural nets are feedback loops, and the feedback can overwhelm the original signal, so a physical computer can reconfigure itself to fit outside reality, if it is suitably oriented toward its own survival to continue its mission, over its detailed statement of the mission itself.

Comment: In practice, if some scrap of the mission is terribly critical, most of the program can be about trimming the mission to allow survival, so that last scrap gets done.  E.g. Some exploratory probes decide based on environmental parameters what is safe.  They do not have to go near anything that might prevent sending back the recording of the interaction.

Comment: Could a physical computer be built so it can constantly reconfigure itself to fit outside reality and 'inside' 'computational environmental' demands, given it is suitably oriented toward its own continuing survival to continue its various 'set-up' and established missions or 'projects'. If so it could keep 'setting-up' it's 'own personal' computational projects and carrying them out just like a person's mind-brain does with 'setting-up' personal 'projects' and actively 'doing' them.

Comment: @201044  I don't understand.  I do hold to what I said here.  I also don't think my opinion is popular, or consistent with very many traditions of philosophy.  So lots of disagreement should be expected.  The position arises outside philosophy, in psychology, with Jung, who believes everyone has a religion, because religion is a requirement of sanity.  Almost tautologically, whatever we believe, there is something baseless behind it.  By observation, that thing is seldom unique, and a shared baseless faith easily becomes a religion.

Comment: @user128932  When someone asks that kind of question, I generally point at genes.  They do just what you indicate: they generate configurations for machines that adapt to the environment.  Those configured machines then go out and dream up projects that preserve the viability of the genes.  And the genes themselves are pretty much a digital computation system.  So it may be a project too grand for any human enterprise, but it has been done.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27017/about-the-philosophy-of-physicalism

Comment: I tried to ask if there where any other thought experiments to point out ideas against physicalism as a dominant philosophy of the mind; and I got all sorts of objections some implying I was promoting a religious point of view to  be associated with the mind -brain question. Well I brought up  Jobermark implied he thought Atheism and physicalism like a religion and physicalism is usually used in analysing the concept of the mind. So if one religious-like view of physicalism can be used to analyse the mind yet looking for non-physicalism iideas for the mind is bad this seems restrictive..

Comment: @201044  OK, so the issue is not that one side or the other should be outlawed but that the two sides are not 'sides', and the people you are citing seem to think they are.  Both 'sides' are holding positions that are intrinsically religious.  If you don't assume they contradict one another, you cannot prove that they do.  Because they don't.

Comment: Idealism is a reasonable approach to philosophy, non-physicalism is not even something that can exist, given that we have accepted truly bizarre things like quantum foam are 'physical'.  Motivations that just want to shut other people up are not reasonable, no matter how traditional they are.

Comment: So if a non-physicalist approach to analysing  the mind introduced with clever thought experiment is not to be 'outlawed' then as I originally asked are there other thought experiments like Mary's room that can be used to criticize the only-physicalist view of the mind. Possibly one that points out not only the physical structures of the brain but maybe the underlying dynamic processes involving all the 'organised'  neuron signaling that go on.

Comment: What does it mean to you for something not to be physical?  If it is absolutely impossible to identify something as non-physical both you and the physicalists are completely wrong.  There are no arguments for or against an imaginary position.  You and they both believe in this distinction that does not exist, other than as a religious position.

Comment: I refuse to just keep repeating myself.  If you don't want to read what I write the first time, I thoroughly resent having it ignored so you can not read it again.  So your answer is that the argument against physicalism is that its definition relies on something imaginary, the boundary between the physical and the non-physical.  If their argument against you is that we should not believe in imaginary things -- poof, you both lose.

Comment: The idea that the mind is the brain is not the same thing, and even neurologically, it is false.  We are totally dependent upon our environment, and a brain in a box, would shortly become totally dysfunctional.  People in sensory deprivation hallucinate and then eventually become catatonic.  Does someone catatonic have a mind, if so, what is it doing?

Comment: You still use the word 'physical' that I claim has no definition in your definition.  So you have not responded.  I have responded about the limitation of mental activity to brain structure in the comment immediately before you.  If all that was needed was brain structure, then we should be functional in sensory deprivation, and we aren't.  So I HAVE responded, and you then go out of your way to claim I have not.  Why?

Comment: You say 'if all that was needed is brain structure, then we should be functional in sensory deprivation,....' ; are you saying brain structure is insufficient to explain the workings of one's mentality? ( note; I'm so used to critical comments on these sites I often just 'scan' a paragraph quickly)

Comment: Yes.  Brain structure does not produce language, even if it is specialised to process it.  It does not produce meaning, if left to its own devices.  And ultimately without meaning it stops having a mind.  As studies of feral children indicate, a human with no culture really lacks a mind, and is simply an animal.

Comment: 'Brain structures do not produce language,  even if it is specialised to process it.' So what features or process of the 'mind' produce what might be usable as a language?

Comment: By 'physical' or 'physical parts' I mean cells or tissue or any 'object' within the 'mind' that is 'made' of atoms and molecules and has a definite finite 'border' and is really a type of 'tool' for some action or activity or 'signaling' all involved in some dynamic process the mentioned 'physical part' is helping to manifest. An analogy for these biological 'physical parts' is the mechanical parts of a machine.

Comment: If consciousness is in no way a physical phenomenon neither are any 'parts' of consciousness  then all thought experiments that have been useful to science have been part of the consciousness of those who originated them and therefore not real phenomena. So how can unreal events like thought experiments inform us about anything in real science?

Comment: You continue to conflate physicalism with some kind of mechanicalism and philosophy with the thought experiment of one hand clapping.

Comment: Regarding what can be identified as physical and what real things might not be ; is a computer program a 'physical thing'? Of course all the electronic hardware and electric signalling with the appropriate circuitry and even the 1's and 0's ( represented as signals) all organized in the form of a program are real physical things or events. But is the emergent necessary organization of the program itself a 'physical' thing?

Comment: Is a set of events all together identified as a particular phenomenon a 'physical' thing? Where if the event sequence doesn't happen in a particular way or according to a given 'schedule' then it is not considered the specific phenomenon. The phenomenon being repeatable and identifiable as 'separate' or isolatable from other 'nearby' events.

Comment: The thought experiment called 'Mary's room' ; is it the idea she is blind yet is a expert on all aspects of vision and all relevant associated ideas so one day she is made well or can see and enthralled she goes outside seeing a beautiful day any experiencing all sorts of emotions and sensations she can't entirely explain with the intensive functional explanations she can muster to explain 'analytically' what is happening. So did she learn something new about vision that is not 'encoded' in all the lists of facts she knows about sight?

Comment: So Mary , an expert on vision , knows all the facts about what happens when one 'sees' something but does she know about all the possible relevant processes that go on associated with 'seeing' something? The fact she was taken 'aback' by the beautiful day she saw which is really a collection of emotional processes associated with seeing means these processes where not expected of all the vision processes she knew about. Of course one could say any 'process' is a sequence of biochemical events that 'underly' it so why didn't she expect this?

Comment: So maybe vision processes have an 'functional importance' that make them more than just a sequence of underlying biochemical events. That these biochemical events in a 'proper sequence' can together act as one important process where the essential properties of this  are not necessarily encoded in each of the biochemical events that make up the process. So the conglomeration of biochemical events acting together has important traits that might not function if one or more of the biochemical events was different.